# How to create a CustomUser for authentication from external Database in Django?

Tags: django, django-models

I created a Django CustomUser model with a UserManager. It is working just fine but I didn't find a way to use this model with a MyQSL secondary database (not default one) which already contains some data.

Setting file :

```py
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'default',
        'HOST': '',
        'USER': '',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'PORT': '',
    },
    'secondary': {
        'NAME': 'secondary',
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'HOST': '',
        'USER': '',
        'PASSWORD': '',
    },
```

models:

```py
class CustomUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, username, password=None):
        user_obj = self.model(
            username=username
        )
        user_obj.set_password(password)
        user_obj.save(using=self._db)
        return user_obj

    def create_superuser(self, username, password):
        user_obj = self.create_user(
            username=username,
            password=password,
        )
        user_obj.save(using=self._db)
        return user_obj


class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False, unique=True)
    email = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=200, blank=False)
    first_name = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=200, blank=False, db_column='firstName')
    last_name = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=200, blank=False, db_column='lastName')
    last_login = timezone.now()
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'

    objects = CustomUserManager()

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'secondary'
```

I can get the data from views just like this `queryset = CustomUser.objects.using('secondary_database');`

But this doesn't help in authentication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/multi-db/#an-example, you will pre-select a proper database before initializing your queryset.

Alternatively try to override `get_queryset` method on your `CustomUserManager` class .

Btw, have you updated your `AUTH_USER_MODEL` setting? - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model

Comment: Hello @Tomasz Chonja, I will try to edit the AuthRouter class thank you. 
Yes i have updated the `AUTH_USER_MODEL` and tried thing with a custom Authentication Backends but I didn't get what i want yet.